# Use Dominated convergence theorem to show that $f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^3}$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let

> $$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^3},$$

how can we show that f is differentiable everywhere by using the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? I know this theorem as saying that the integral and the limit can change each other under the dominating condition. But how can we use it in this question?Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can first rewrite the sum as an integral over counting measure $dk$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \int_\mathbb{N} \frac{\cos (kx) }{ k^3 } dk$

> $f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \int_\mathbb{N} \frac{\cos (k(x+h)) - \cos(kx)}{ hk^3 } dk$
>  
>  We bound the numerator by $kh$ using mean value theorem. Hence we have a dominating function $1/k^2$ and apply the DCT to pull the limit through.

Answer (score 0):

For any sequence $x_n \to a$, write 
$$g_n(k) = \frac{1}{k^3} \frac{\cos kx_n - \cos ka}{x_n-a}.$$

The sequence $g_n(k)$ converges pointwise to $g(k) = -\frac{1}{k^2} \sin ka$.

Uniformly in $n$, we have by the mean-value theorem that $|g_n(k)| \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$, and the function $\frac{1}{k^2}$ is integrable with respect to counting measure $dk$.  Therefore by the dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(a)}{x_n-a} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_k  g_n(k) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int g_n \, dk = \int g \, dk = -\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2} \sin ka.$$

Since the sequence $x_n$ was arbitrary, we have 
$$f'(a) = -\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2} \sin ka.$$